# How to convert nested dict to nested list to find value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dict my_dict in python:

```
{'version': '1.1', 
'time': '1520541234', 
'car': [{'id': '123', 'locationX': '-0.673606', 'locationY': '23.5310399', '@id': 'http://URL', 'standardname': 'value1', 'name': 'value_1'}, 
        {'id': '124', 'locationX': '0.O683', 'locationY': '48.42', '@id': 'htt://URL2', 'standardname': 'value2', 'name': 'value_2'}, 
        {'id': '125', 'locationX': '42.532', 'locationY': '12.424', '@id': 'http://URL3', 'standardname': 'value3', 'name': 'value_3'}, 
        ....
```

I want to check if one specific value is in the dic. I saw it seems easier in a list so I try to convert my my_dict to a list:

```
my_list=(list(my_dict.items()))
```

Now I'm searching for my value

```
any('value' in sl for sl in my_list)
```

But this does not work. What am I missing here?

Comment: please post the dictionary itself, not `dict_values`

Comment: What about something like `any('value' in dict_values().values())`

Comment: @JoeIddon updated

Comment: `in` doesn't recurse, so if you're looking for a specific value in one of the `car` dict items, you'll need to do that recursion in your loop.

Comment: Maybe you really want to search `my_dict['car']`, not `my_dict`?

Comment: Who told you that it's easier to search in a list? You can search `my_dict.items()` just as easily as `my_list`, and without the extra line of code, the potential for confusion, the cost of a copy, etc.

Comment: Also, in what sense does this "not work"? Your dict doesn't have any items that contain "value", and the `any` expression correctly returns `False`. Your dict does have some values that are dicts that have values that are strings that contain the substring `"value"`; is that what you're trying to search for?